# Can struct type be value of bpf hash map?

Tags: hashmap, ebpf, bpf

I want the value in the bpf hash map be a struct, but it doesn't work. who knows if this is allowed by BPF? code like blow.

also, I have the second question, how can I call a kernel function in the bpf program?

```
typedef struct my_value {
    u64 ts;
    unsigned char opcode;
    unsigned int pages;
    pid_t pid;
} MY_VAL;

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, 8192);
    //__type(key, pid_t);
    __type(key, u64);
    __type(value, MY_VAL);
} _start SEC(".maps");
```

when I use

```
struct my_value e;
e.pages= 10;

u64 pate = 0x456;

bpf_map_update_elem(&_start, &pate, &e, BPF_ANY);
```

there is error :

*79: (85) call bpf_map_update_elem#2 invalid indirect read from stack off -32+0 size 8 processed 51 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 3 peak_states 3 mark_read 1*

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? Did you try without defining it as a typedef?

Comment: Yes it should work. What error message do you get? As for calling kernel functions, you cannot just use _any_ function, but you can call one of the available bpf helpers from your program, see [this page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) for some documentation, or look for examples with e.g. `bpf_map_update_elem()` or `bpf_trace_printk()`.

Comment: @Qeole  I want to call a function which is not in bpf helper, but it is in the Linux kernel, which is external, for example, get_unaligned_be32()., how to call this kind of kernel function??

Comment: @pchaigno  bpf_map_update_elem(&_start, &pate, &e, BPF_ANY); will fail.  do you know how to update it?

Comment: I'm surprised Qeole's solution didn't work. Could you share the full program and the full logs from the verifier?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your error: The verifier rejects your program if you try to update the map with uninitialised date from the stack, which is what happens when you create your value.

Try to initialise the whole struct:

```c
struct my_value e;
memset(&e, 0, sizeof(e));
e.pages= 10;
```

Regarding your second question: You can call eBPF [*helpers*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) from your eBPF program, you can call [a very few white-listed functions from the kernel](https://ebpf.io/blog/ebpf-updates-2021-05#core), but you cannot call just any function from the kernel at this time. Some functions that do not depend on your kernel's internals may be reimplemented in your program, though.

Comment: hi Qeole, you are right, it works now. the error is another one, not because of the update. thanks.